# LOGICAL ERROR IN SELECT QUERY

Tags: mysql, asp.net

```
mysql> Create Procedure sp_Getnewtask(IN sdate datetime, IN edate datetime,IN sid   int,IN tid int,OUT outmsg varchar(50))
-> begin
-> if not exists(
-> SELECT * FROM tbltask WHERE (startdate BETWEEN sdate AND edate)OR (enddate BETWEEN sdate AND edate) OR (sdate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate) OR (edate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate) OR Sid=Sid OR Tid=tid ) then
-> set outmsg = 'ADDED SUCESSFULLY';
-> else
-> set outmsg = 'RECORD ALREADY PRESENT';
-> end if;
-> end $$

mysql> select * from tbltask;

| tblid | startdate           | enddate             | Sid  | Lid  |

|     1 | 2011-05-20 00:00:00 | 2011-05-29 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

it displays as record already exists even there is not record present in the database,

If i delete the sid,tid from the select query it is working correctly,
Please suggest some idea in order to chk run output correctly

when i tried to call the procedure,
it returns as,

```
 mysql> call sp_Getnewtask('2011-05-20','2011-05-29',6,8,@outmsg);
-> select @outmsg;
-> $$
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

```
| @outmsg                |

| RECORD ALREADY PRESENT |
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

but my actual result should as 'ADDED SUCESSFULLY'

Comment: You're using `OR` in your `WHERE` criteria with `Sid=Sid` - that will always be true!  Remove `OR Sid=Sid OR Tid=tid` and it should work.

Comment: but i want to check the with sid and tid too.

Comment: rename your input variables to be different than the field names in the table.  so inSid and inTid.  Engine is likely having trouble knowing if you want to compare variable to field, field to field, or variable to variable.  and I don't see a TID in the table.  I see LID...  So this means TID input is compared to TID input... is that what you want?

Comment: I tried changing tid to tutorid and sid to saveid but I am getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

"ADDED SUCCESSFULLY" should only be reported if no records were selected in your select statement, but given your input variables in `call sp_Getnewtask('2011-05-20','2011-05-29',6,8,@outmsg);` You actually trigger four of your 6 conditions in all of your WHERE's OR'd conditions.

Edited to add:

I have run the following (results included). What I've done is change the names of your variables so that you don't end up with an always true WHERE statement (`SID=SID or TID=TID` will always be true). I've also changed the `SELECT` statement to match your field names in your table you gave as an example.

```
CREATE TABLE tbltask
    (
        tblid int,
        startdate datetime,
        enddate datetime,
        sid int,
        lid int
    );

INSERT INTO `tbltask`(`tblid`, `startdate`, `enddate`) VALUES (1, '2011-05-20 00:00:00','2011-05-29 00:00:00');

DELIMITER //
CREATE Procedure sp_Getnewtask(IN sdate datetime, IN edate datetime,IN inSid int,IN inLid int,OUT outmsg varchar(50))
begin
if not exists
(
    SELECT * FROM tbltask WHERE (startdate BETWEEN sdate AND edate)OR (enddate BETWEEN sdate AND edate) OR (sdate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate) OR (edate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate) OR Sid=inSid OR Lid=inLid
) then
    set outmsg = 'ADDED SUCCESSFULLY';
else
    set outmsg = 'RECORD ALREADY PRESENT';
end if;
end
//

call sp_Getnewtask('2011-05-20','2011-05-29',6,8,@outmsg);
select @outmsg;

RECORD ALREADY PRESENT

call sp_Getnewtask('2010-05-20','2010-05-29',6,8,@outmsg);
select @outmsg;

ADDED SUCCESSFULLY
```

As it stands, this appears to be doing what it ought to do. If either date range should intersect it will find the record. If they don't intersect but the sid OR lid match, then it will find the record. Finding the record makes it report "Record Already Present"

Comment: the same OR conditions is working perfectly when the tid and sid is removed from the select query.

Comment: If you remove TID and SID from the WHERE Statement you get "Added Successfully" when you do a `call sp_Getnewtask('2011-05-20','2011-05-29',6,8,@outmsg);`?

Comment: yeah I know that but I need to chk my query with the sid and tid also the same query is correctly working in MS SQL but it is not working IN MYSQL

Comment: No. I was asking you in order to clarify "the same OR conditions is working perfectly when the tid and sid is removed from the select query." Just removing those two conditions from your WHERE statement should still have it reporting "Records Already Present", but you say that removing those fixed it?

Comment: yeah it is working since the logic is working correctly .. while adding the particular Id's it is co-relating with my before logic.. there occurs the issue my be we can modify the query for checking all the date, sid and tid. FROM code (startdate BETWEEN sdate AND edate)OR (enddate BETWEEN sdate AND edate) OR (sdate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate) OR (edate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate)  is working pefect the main problem is adding SID and TID condition along with it